# Can't figure out how to calculate CRC7

Tags: c++, c, crc

I need to calculate a CRC7 for a series of bytes 
My polynom x^7+x^3+1 
Here is a function I wrote:

```
unsigned char CRC7(const unsigned char message[], const unsigned int length)
{
    const unsigned char poly = 0b10001001;
    unsigned char crc = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        crc ^= message[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            crc = crc & 0x1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ poly : crc >> 1;
    }

    return crc;
}
```

But it gives wrong results. For example 0x82 and 0x04 returns 0x57, while it must be 0x61

This online calculator works for me: http://www.ghsi.de/pages/subpages/Online%20CRC%20Calculation/

I can't just copy paste a function from it, because I need it to return the value as an unsigned char.

Where could I make a mistake?

Comment: I believe those shifts should be left shifts (`<<`), and you should check if msb (`crc & 0x80`) is set.

Comment: Try this site (I didn't check whether it's correct): https://github.com/hazelnusse/crc7/blob/master/crc7.cc

Comment: If the function works for you then you can use it. Starting at the line with `// Convert binary to ASCII` you should be able to generate the output you desire.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, generating a 128 bits large look-up table is probably the correct solution here, if you can afford 128 bytes of extra ROM use.

Comment: Recommend consistent use of index type:  `const unsigned int length... for (unsigned i = 0; i < length; i++ )`  (`int` --> `unsigned`)

Comment: A CRC specification requires more than just the polynomial.  You need bit order, initialization, and final XOR values (sometimes the final XOR value is zero, which is like not having that step).

Comment: _Any_ CRC-7? Do you have a reference for what CRC-7 you need to calculate, and/or example inputs and outputs? In addition to the polynomial, you need the order of bit processing, the initial value, and any final exclusive-or value to fully specify the CRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mimic the [referenced site](http://www.ghsi.de/pages/subpages/Online%20CRC%20Calculation/), shift left and use only 7 bits of the `crc`.

The below xor's `crc` with 8 bits of the message, yet by using `poly << 1`, effectively calculates the CRC on the 7 most significant bits.

```
unsigned char CRC7(const unsigned char message[], const unsigned int length) {
  const unsigned char poly = 0b10001001;
  unsigned char crc = 0;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     crc ^= message[i];
     for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      // crc = crc & 0x1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ poly : crc >> 1;       
      crc = (crc & 0x80u) ? ((crc << 1) ^ (poly << 1)) : (crc << 1);
    }
  }
  //return crc;
  return crc >> 1;
}
```

Of course `const unsigned char poly = 0b10001001;` could be replaced

```
const unsigned char poly = 0b10001001;
const unsigned char poly2 = 0b10001001 << 1;

crc = (crc & 0x80u) ? ((crc << 1) ^ poly2) : (crc << 1);
```

---

Test

```
int main(void) {
  printf("%x\n", CRC7((unsigned char*)"\x82\x04",2));
}
```

Output

```
61
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I seems I confused CRC7 with CRC8. I thought the only difference is that we doesn't count the most significant bit.

Comment: @EugeneMart: That is the only difference between a 7-bit and an 8-bit CRC.  The other differences are not related to the CRC polynomial order.